# Tui image editor, adding two drawable shapes

Tags: reactjs, toast-ui-image-editor

I need to only show two shapes in my custom Tui image editor, a rectangle and a circle, nothing more nothing less.

I added the rectangle and it works perfectly but if I add another function to add a circle and draw either or first the and then select the other, it still draws the first item. (if you click on a circle and draw, then click on the rectangle and draw then it draws a circle)

I am not sure how I can get this to function properly.

here is my two functions for my circle and rectangle.

```
  const onAddCircle = () => {
    imageEditorRef.current.startDrawingMode('SHAPE');
    if (imageEditorRef.current.getDrawingMode() !== 'SHAPE') {
      const { height } = imageEditorRef.current.getCanvasSize();
      imageEditorRef.current.startDrawingMode('SHAPE');
      imageEditorRef.current.setDrawingShape('circle', {
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: COLOR_STATUS_ORANGE,
        strokeWidth: height / 100,
        isRegular: true,
      });
    }
  };
```

```
  const onAddRectangle = () => {
    if (imageEditorRef.current.getDrawingMode() !== 'SHAPE') {
      const { height } = imageEditorRef.current.getCanvasSize();
      imageEditorRef.current.startDrawingMode('SHAPE');
      imageEditorRef.current.clearObjects();
      imageEditorRef.current.setDrawingShape('rect', {
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: COLOR_STATUS_ORANGE,
        strokeWidth: height / 100,
        isRegular: true,
      });
    }
  };
```

and they are triggered by buttons

```
  <button
   onClick={onAddCircle}
   color="green"
  />
```

```
 <button
   onClick={onAddRectangle}
   color="red"
  />
```

I've tried adding `imageEditorRef.current.clearDrawingShape();` to the beginning of the functions but it says its not a function because it doesn't exist. then I tried adding     `imageEditorRef.current.clearObjects();` but that clears everything that it draw by that shape.

I've looked their documentation as well and there is nothing on how to actually clear `shape cache` before drawing or selecting another shape.

Could someone please help ?

Comment: Can you share a github link or an online code snippet like stackblitz so that we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

Ive combined both functions into one added a prop called shape, and it checks if the prop is set to either or and then if it is then it uses that logic else it clears the drawing board.

```
  const drawShape = (Shape) => {
    const { height } = imageEditorRef.current.getCanvasSize();
    imageEditorRef.current.startDrawingMode('SHAPE');
    if (Shape === 'circle') {
      imageEditorRef.current.setDrawingShape('circle', {
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: COLOR_STATUS_ORANGE,
        strokeWidth: height / 100,
        isRegular: true,
      });
    } else if (Shape === 'rectangle') {
      imageEditorRef.current.setDrawingShape('rect', {
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: COLOR_STATUS_ORANGE,
        strokeWidth: height / 100,
        isRegular: true,
      });
    } else {
      imageEditorRef.current.stopDrawingMode();
    }
  };
```